# Magit appends '^M' (return) characters to git results

Tags: magit

In the magit-status window Magit shows '^M" for many things. This is on FreeBSD, which should be using newlines instead:[image: Shot of magit-status]

This is, I think, the reason the push doesn't work right. From the magit-process buffer:

git … push -v origin master^M:refs/heads/master

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Shot in the dark: does changing `magit-process-connection-type` to `nil` fix it?

Comment: @Drew I think it's kind of obvious: Magit appends ^M where it shouldn't: how to change this (or is by design, a bug, a known bug)? PS. I'd look into `~/.gitconfig` if there is one, or `.gitattributes` and the plethora of other Git configuration files where you may have accidentally specified (or forgot to specify) how Git needs to handle newlines. Unfortunately, there are just too many ways to do this and none easy to understand or find... But if this behavior is consistent between different repositories on your computer, then the chance is it's in some global config...

Comment: @wvxvw: It might be obvious to some readers, but it generally helps, and doesn't hurt, to pose question(s) explicitly. Even in your comment you raise more than one question: *how to change this?* *Is it a (known) bug?* *Is it by design?* (and implicitly, if so, why? what does it mean?) *What is the cause?* *Is there a global config that affects this?* Note that I didn't vote to close the question as unclear. My comment was a suggestion to improve the question by making it explicit.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen this on Windows when using tramp to connect to a remote directory on Linux. (I thought the ^M were Windows line breaks; but not in your case apparently.) Once it happens, the normal emacs Find-File mechanism breaks, due I think to an invalid default-directory. I haven't isolated Steps to Reproduce yet though.

Answer (score 4):

That was fixed in `v2.6.0`, see [the release announcement](https://emacsair.me/2016/03/29/magit-2.6).

Edit: Hm, actually after looking at the screenshot a little more carefully, I think this might not actually be enough in your case. This is very strange and I am guessing that "something" is terribly misconfigured. (And it's not Magit. Magit does not "appends ^M where it shouldn't". Instead it does "not make any attempt to remove ^M, because there aren't supposed to be any in the first place".)